# Completely remove mysql 5.7

Tags: server, 18.04, mysql, uninstall

I have Ubuntu 18.04. I want to completely remove MySql server with all the files and folders.

I've tried Synaptic Packet Manager, but since there are some error packets, I can't do it using that.
What command should I use in Terminal for complete cleaning? Will I then be able to install everything again and then to work again?

ps. I installed full LAMP using tasksel, I hope it won't influence on that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo apt purge mysql-*
```

Afterwards run:

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

To install MySQL again follow guide [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-18-04).